# Can't access index.php after modifying the 000-default.conf to suit dms setup

Tags: apache2

So I've been trying to install Seeddms. I just re-flashed the os on my current samba server and wanted to add this DMS to just make life easier. I've flowed the steps mentioned on this website ([Install Guide for old Seeddms](https://myanwyn.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/how-to-install-seeddms-on-ubuntu.html)). I am aware that this is for the old version of Seeddms and have changed all the version related code.

Question is...

What haven't I done to allow access to the index.php page after modifying the 000-default.conf ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /seeddms “/home/www-data/seeddms50x/seeddms-5.0.8/“
    <Directory "/home/www-data/seeddms50x/seeddms-5.0.8/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> Located in -> "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/"

I try and access the install page using the web address of

http://steve/seeddms/install
(**steve being the name of the samba server)

However, no luck.

Any Ideas ?